# Lotus Notes - Go to URL from a picture

Tags: image, url, lotus-notes

I insert an image on a page and then I added a default hotspot button on it. The content type is Content and the value is computed: `@URLOpen("www.ibm.com")`.

But when I click the image it shows: Formula must evaluate to text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Content Type as `URL` and simply enter Content Value as `www.ibm.com` in your Hotspot properties.

The error comes because a text value (URL) is required in Content Value and `@URLOpen` does not return text value.